# How to organize multi-stage Dockerfiles for multi-module microservices with common modules

Tags: docker, dockerfile, multi-module, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a gRPC microservices project with following structure:

```
- common (common protobuf definitions)
- microservices
  - ms1
    ..
  - msN
```

Now I want to add multi stage Dockerfiles for each microservice.
The problem is that I have this common module which I need to build the rest of the projects. I can't reference the sources outside the microservice project in Dockerfile.

So the only posibility I see is to have one Dockerfile in the root folder that builds all the images:

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-eclipse-temurin-17 AS builder
COPY ./ /usr/app
RUN mvn -f /usr/app/pom.xml clean package


FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/microservices/ms1/target/ms1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/ms1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/ms1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

But still I have to build all the project in builder image.
One other option I see is to create separate Docker images for builder and then referencing it inside of the microservice Dockerfile by tag. But how can I trigger rebuild for builder image when building microservice image.

Are there any other options? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a multistage [dockerfile with arguments (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) and [maven's `--also-make` command line option (`maven.apache.org`)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html#command-line-options):

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-eclipse-temurin-17 AS builder
ARG RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE # e.g. service/ms1
COPY ./ /usr/app

# specify the specific project to build via "-pl", we could also use "-f /usr/app/${PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE}/pom.xml"
# we specify --also-make to also build the dependencies
RUN mvn -pl /usr/app/${PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE} --also-make clean package

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
ARG RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE # e.g. service/ms1
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/${RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE}/target/*.jar /usr/app/service.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/service.jar"]
```

Should the `target`-directory contains more than one `.jar`-file, we can exclude all unwanted `.jar`-files through a [`.dockerignore`-file (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file), e.g. in the module's root directory.

We can then build a particular microservice by calling [`docker build` with `--build-arg` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)

```
docker build --build-arg RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE=services/ms1 --tag services/ms1 .
docker build --build-arg RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ADAPTER_MODULE=services/ms2 --tag services/m22 .
...
```

Notice, however, that each build has still to re-build the dependency modules; they are not shared across builds. Also, each build has to re-download all maven dependencies. [This article at `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-cache-maven-dependencies) shows how to use a host directory as maven cache.